# ASP NET MVC RAZOR Upload Multiple Images FileList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new in asp net and I have a List of images and I want to send through javascript to the controller.

I'm using FileList and here is an example.
.Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.description, "Escolha as Imagens", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" />
    <br>
    <div id="preview"></div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleFileSelect(evt) {

            var files = evt.target.files;
            var f = files[0];
            //kiem tra co fai file anh
            if (f.type.match('image.*')) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                    return function(e) {
                        var span = document.createElement('span');
                        span.innerHTML = [
                            '<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name),
                            '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'
                        ].join('');
                        document.getElementById('preview').insertBefore(span, null);
                    };
                })(f);

                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        }

        $('#files').change(function(evt) {
            handleFileSelect(evt);
        });
        $('#preview').on('click',
            '.remove_img_preview',
            function() {
                $(this).parent('span').remove();
            });

        $('#btnSave').click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Dishes/Create',
                data: { files: files },
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                datatype: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //do your own thing
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
}
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="footer text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-fill btn-info" name="btnSave" id="btnSave">Inserir novo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.idTypeDish = new SelectList(db.TypeDish, "idTypeDish", "name");
        return View();
    }



    // POST: Dishes/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {


        return View();

    }
```

In the controller, files are always null.
I'm using that example, http://jsfiddle.net/Lwczca6p/1/, I just adapt to my project.

Comment: You probably don't need to do all of that, but if you're going to allow multiple files to be uploaded, then you'll want to add `multiple="multiple"` to your file input (assuming you're using html5 anyway

Comment: @Ortund Ya I know what you mean, but If he selects 2 images, then he goes select another one, what happens? I have a FileList, I can't send the FileList to the controller?

Comment: @Ortund  I'm using all that code, because, before uploading to the server, the user can preview the image and deleted if he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few problems. First, you're trying to use `files` with your AJAX, but that variable was defined in the scope of another function (i.e. you don't have access to it here). Second, when using jQuery's `$.ajax` to do a file upload, you need to set the `processData` option to `false`. Here's how I would handle it:

```
$('#MyForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this); // `this` is the form instance
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/handler',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // do something on success
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // do something on error
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, but how would it work on the controller? What parameters would I have instead? I never used FormData before.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, first create a model for your view:

```
public class FileModel  
{  
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please select file.")]  
    [Display(Name ="Browse File")]  
    public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }  

}
```

Then, edit your view to this (to enable upload many files you need to put multiple="multiple" in your element):

```
@model Models.FileModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))  
{  
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  

    <div class="form-horizontal">  
        <hr />  
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  
        <div class="form-group">  
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.files, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })  
            <div class="col-md-10">  
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, "", new { @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple" })  
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.files, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">  
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">  
                <input type="submit"  value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />  
            </div>  
        </div>  

        </div>  
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer! But thats not really what I want...I want to be able to select an image one by one, and in the end send the array of files to the controller.

Comment: ohh ok. Have you tried to use Dropzone? http://www.dropzonejs.com/ I used it once with asp.net mvc. If you want, I can send you an example.

Comment: No, I never used dropzone, but from what I read it instantly uploads to the server, and that's not what I want... I want to be able to add and delete images and then upload when the product is registered. But yes I would like an example if you don't mind.

Comment: I wrote this post in my blog about dropzone, I hope it helps. http://tiagoavilablog.com/utilizando-dropzonejs-com-asp-net-mvc/